# Trying to get text over a slideshow responsive

Tags: css, responsive

I am trying to get the text "Wing Me Up" over the slideshow responsive so it resizes with the image, I have already tried to take out the position: absolute; and nothing seems to be working. I dont want any inline styling in my HTML, just pure CSS.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2em;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-7deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); 
  /*For IE support*/
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img/wings.png" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Wing me up</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `font-size:3.75em`

Comment: you could use vw and vh as font size units

Comment: The container of text increases or decreases so does the text

Comment: It is responsive but on a full desktop view the font size doesn't change.

Comment: Because `.mySlides .fade` is not responsive

Comment: How would I make them responsiveness?

Comment: You can use media queries for this

Comment: @AdnanAhmed it depends. You have to post the code

Comment: font-size: %;   ... 90,100 or 110 ...

Comment: Okay, when I use the em the text is responsiveness however I cannot resize the text. When I use percentages it is not responsiveness, Added a media tag and nothing seems to be happening. Can I put the text inside a div box and edit it that way?